# can't find opencv2/surface_matching.hpp, no namespace ppf_match_3d

Tags: opencv

I have read in these sites:

- http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de6/namespacecv_1_1ppf__match__3d.html#gsc.tab=0
- http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/surface_matching/doc/surface_matching.html

About APIs to use iterative closest point (ICP) algorithm for surface matching. But I couldn't find `opencv2/surface_matching.hpp` in `opencv3.0.0`.

Is this normal or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They move it to OpenCV contrib : https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for